# What class or method needs to be overridden or implemented to customize only the authenticate logic for Shiro?

Tags: java, shiro, websecurity

I have been able to implement basic authentication using Shiro.  I would now like to write custom logic to implement only the authentication step of the process i.e., when user credentials are supplied, are the credentials valid (and potentially what roles does the user have if these two pieces of logic are coupled in the logic of the framework).  What class(s)/method(s) do I need to override to enable this?  I'm assuming  I would create a custom implementation to replace org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter but I'm not sure what method(s) in the class hierarch need to be modified/overwritten.

My shiro.ini file looks like this:

```
# ---
#
# ini file for shiro
#
# ---

[main]
# authc.usernameParam = uid
# authc.passwordParam = pwd
# authc.failureKeyAttribute = shiroLoginFailure

[users]
admin = admin, ROLE_ADMIN

[roles]
ROLE_ADMIN = *

[urls]
/app/** = authcBasic
```

The relevant part of my web.xml looks like this:

```
<!-- 
*
* shiro stuff
*
-->

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Full implementation is available here:

https://github.com/NACHC-CAD/web-security-example

Basic authentication is here:

https://github.com/NACHC-CAD/web-security-example/releases/tag/v1.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to define a custom `Realm`: https://shiro.apache.org/realm.html

Specifically, you probably want to extend `org.apache.shiro.realm. AuthorizingRealm` and implement the `doGetAuthenticationInfo` and `doGetAuthorizationInfo`  methods.